# Discriminated unions of objects containing union types in typescript

Tags: typescript

Please suggest a better title, I am not sure what exactly to ask.

I have a type definition that looks like this:

```js
type Animal =
  | {
    'species': 'cat'
    'action': 'meow'
  }
  | {
    'species': 'cat'
    'action': 'whine'
  }
  | {
    'species': 'dog' | 'tree'
    'action': 'bark'
  };
```

I want to define a conditional type `ActionsFor<S>` that results in a narrowed-down type of the given species. For example:

```js
type CatActions = ActionsFor<'cat'> // should be 'meow' | 'whine'
type DogActions = ActionsFor<'dog'> // should be 'bark'
type TreeActions = ActionsFor<'tree'> // should be 'bark'
type BarkActions = ActionsFor<'dog'|'tree'> // should be 'bark'
```

My current attempt is close but does not work as I want with the unioned species:

```js
type ActionFor<S extends Animal['species']> = Extract<Animal, {species: S}>['action']
```

Which results in:

```js
type CatActions = ActionsFor<'cat'> // correct - 'meow' | 'whine'
type DogActions = ActionsFor<'dog'> // WRONG - never
type TreeActions = ActionsFor<'tree'> // WRONG - never
type BarkActions = ActionsFor<'dog'|'tree'> // correct - 'bark'
```

How can I redefine ActionsFor to do what I want?

Comment: This is behaving oddly: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?jsx=2#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

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. This seems to work, but if anyone can get it shorter or more elegant I'm all ears!

```js
type ActionFor<S extends Animal['species']> = Exclude<Animal, {species: Exclude<Animal['species'], S>}>['action']
```

Comment: Also if anyone has a good way to pull that out into a generic type like "ExtractWithUnions" or something that would be cool